# Redirect to website in a new window or tab

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I need the timeout function, which works, but opening a new tab or window isn't.

How to change the code so when it redirects after five seconds it forwards the user to another site, but in a new window or tab?

```js
$('#google').click(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.href = "https://google.com", '_blank'
      }, 5000);
      });
```

Comment: `window.open()` ?

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped you out, so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 4):

To open a new window you have to call `window.open()` function.

So your code becomes something like so:

```
$('#google').click(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
      window.open('https://google.com') //this by default opens a new window
   }, 5000);
});
```

**UPDATE**
This will probably lead to the browser blocking the popup (or opening of a new tab). If you want to open the new tab you will have to do it as soon as the user performs the click event, any delay will lead to blocking of the popup.

Comment: Thanks that works, yet Chrome by default is blocking the new tab from opening.  Any work around to ensure a new window or tab is opened in modern browsers?

Comment: `window.open` after `setTimout` or any other asynchronous event will block the popup.. Make sure you invoke the `window.open` as soon as user initiates the event...

Comment: Exactly as @Rayon mentioned.. The window.open() event should be called upon a user action (at that particular moment) or it will be blocked.

Comment: Oh yeah i need to show a bootstrap modal telling the business user they are being redirected to another site.  Sounds like this can't be done?

Comment: Yes but the user has to perform an action if you want them to open a new popup / window.. or else you can simply use `document.location.href="http://google.com";`